# Terraform AWS: override root device size using aws_launch_template and block_device_mappings

Tags: amazon-ec2, terraform

I dont find a way to override root size device using **block_device_mappings** in **aws_launch_template** with terraform aws.

I know I can specify an extra volume size doing for example:

```
block_device_mappings {
        device_name = "/dev/xvda"
        ebs {
        volume_size = "${var.frontend_kong_volume_size}"
        volume_type = "${var.frontend_kong_volume_type}"
        delete_on_termination = "true"
        }
    }
```

but I get a new disk in the VM with those specifications.
But what I want to do is resize the root disk.

Can you help me to figure out how to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Answer (score 9):

**block_device_mappings** is for additional block devices.

You have to know device where root device mounted. for example for centos 7 AMI it's `/dev/sda1`

```
resource "aws_launch_template" "foobar" {
  name_prefix   = "foobar"
  image_id      = "ami-9887c6e7"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  block_device_mappings {
    device_name = "/dev/sda1"

    ebs {
      volume_size = 40
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "bar" {
  availability_zones = ["us-east-1a"]
  desired_capacity   = 1
  max_size           = 1
  min_size           = 1

  launch_template = {
    id      = "${aws_launch_template.foobar.id}"
    version = "$$Latest"
  }
}
```

But remember that update of volume size in terraform will not take effect to running instances. So you will have to replace instances to increase volume size.

Comment: in your aws_autoscaling_group you either use aws_launch_template or aws_launch_configuration. https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/autoscaling_group.html
Note: You must specify either launch_configuration, launch_template, or mixed_instances_policy

Comment: The OP was asking how to override a root device size in an aws_launch_template and NOT in an aws_launch_configuration.

Comment: @DmytroLeonenko you right, I was confused with last terraform docs, plus mostly used `aws_autoscaling_group` along with` aws_launch_configuration`. Updating my answer with my last tests of `aws_launch_template`

Comment: Also, I've never seen /dev/sda1 as a root device in a Linux AMI. It was always /dev/xvda. Note, that sda1 is a partition name, not a device name.

Comment: @DmytroLeonenko for Centos 7 ami from snippet above it's `/dev/sda1`
You right about that it's partition name in common, but in that particular AMI, root device setup like this. You can run terraform to check it.

Comment: If you're using an "aws_ami" data object, you can fetch the block device name using `tolist(data.aws_ami.myami.block_device_mappings)[0].device_name`